# graphical representation of matrix in R using image()

Tags: r

I have an N*M matrix that I want to visualize using image() in R. However, the default is to make the last column the first row. How do I transform a matrix that I have so that image displays the matrix with row 1 column 1 being the upper-left position of the image?

Here is an example:

```
dat = c(0, 0.333333333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.196428571428571, 0.303571428571429, 
0.214285714285714, 0.0535714285714286, 0.0357142857142857, 4e-05, 
0.0522875816993464, 0.245098039215686, 0.333333333333333, 0.274509803921569, 
0.0130718954248366, 0.00264106145251397, 0.00846262341325811, 
0.148095909732017, 0.337094499294781, 0.411847672778561, 0.0578279266572638, 
0.0435311336717428, 0.00511073253833049, 0.0604770017035775, 
0.240204429301533, 0.552810902896082, 0.117546848381601, 0.139510231023102, 
0.00668896321070234, 0.0301003344481605, 0.1438127090301, 0.42809364548495, 
0.374581939799331)
mat = matrix(dat,6,6)
image(mat)
```

Comment: Why is this question off-topic? When I look at the topics in your hyperlink, data visualization is clearly listed.

Comment: Please read carefully the information in that link. Your question is specifically on implementation: "If the language is statistically oriented (such as R, SAS, Stata, SPSS, etc.), then decide based on the nature of your question: if it needs statistical expertise to understand or answer, ask it here; if it's about the *implementation* of an algorithm, routine *data processing*, or details of the *language*, then please refer to the collection of links to resources we maintain."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to switch rows and columns (transpose function) and reverse the order of the rows.

```
mat2 = t(mat)[6:1,]
image(mat2)
```